# Extract multiple types from tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

That should be obvious, is there some short syntax to get a subtuple?

Something like that:

```
std::tuple<std::string, double, int> myTuple;
std::tuple<std::string, int> subTuple = std::get<std::string, int>(myTuple);
```

Comment: `std::tuple<std::string, int> subTuple { std::get<0>(myTuple), std::get<2>(myTuple) };`?

Comment: What's wrong with two gets? I'm sure you can make it more general with some metatemplate trickery, but is it worth it?

Comment: @rubenvb, I thought the std library has that.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make your own template function, this below implementation requires C++14 (because it requires `std::get<T>`, you can implement it in C++11 yourself):

```
template<typename... R, typename ...Args>
std::tuple<R...> sub_tuple(const std::tuple<Args...>& original) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<R>(original)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::string, double, int> myTuple = std::make_tuple("Hello", 1201.0, 51);
    std::tuple<std::string, int> subTuple = sub_tuple<std::string, int>(myTuple);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(subTuple) << "            " << std::get<1>(subTuple);
}
```

---

Note: this will create a copy for each element in the original tuple

Answer (score 1):

You may use `std::tie` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)):

```
std::tuple<std::string, double, int> myTuple = ...;
std::string a;
int b;
std::tie(a, std::ignore, b) = myTuple;
```